# Show loader until browser starts the file download

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, browser

I want to show the loader till the file download start.
How can I do it?

Here's my code:

```
$('body').prepend("<form method='post' action='create' id='doneform'>" +
"<input type='hidden' name='data' value='" + data + "' >" +
"<input type='hidden' name='brandcolor' value='" + brandcolor + "' >" +
"</form>");

$('#doneform').submit();
```

controller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult create()
{
    ...some stuff....
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
          String.Format("{0}; filename={1}.pdf;size={2}", "attachment", filename, pdfBuffer.Length));
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: You can use `FileResult` instead of `ActionResult` for returning file.

Answer (score 0):

http://syper-blogger.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-detect-start-of-file-download.html

This solves the issue.............

Answer (score -1):

**I don't think this is a proper way of doing, but you can try this**

### HTML

- Get a suitable loading image of type .gif from google or anywhere else.
- Add it into the image tag.

`<img id="loading-image" src="loader.gif" style="display:none" />`

### JavaScript

```
$("#doneform").submit(function(event) {

    $('#loading-image').show();
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).find('input[name="data"]').val();
    var brandcolor = $(this).find('input[name="brandcolor"]').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/[Controller]/[Action]',
      cache: false,
      data:{ data: data, brandcolor:brandcolor },
      success: function(html){
        // Do your stuff.
      },
      complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
      },
      error: function () {
        // Handle any errors here.
      }
    });
});
```

### Controller

You can try **FileResult**

```
public FileResult create()
{
    var fileName = "Something.pdf";
    //Create your pdf file here and save it into a location
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Path for the created pdf file");
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);    
}
```